# 'Jagged' output from dot file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to insert a .dot graph from an sklearn decision tree into a pyplot subplot, and have been struggling to do so. The library pygraphviz is refusing to work on my Windows system, so I've used the following to insert the images:

```
from subprocess import check_call
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

gridSpec = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2)
treeSubPlot = plt.subplot(gridSpec.new_subplotspec((2, 1)))
treeSubPlot.tick_params(axis = "both", which = "both", bottom = False, top = False, labelbottom = False, right = False, left = False, labelleft = False)
treeSubPlot.set_xlabel("Final model")

# Obtain the size of a single plot in inches to inform the dot picture creator.
height = treeSubPlot.get_window_extent().y1 - treeSubPlot.get_window_extent().y0
width = treeSubPlot.get_window_extent().x1 - treeSubPlot.get_window_extent().x0

check_call(['dot','-Tpng', "-Gsize=" + str(width/100) + "," + str(height/100) + "!", "-Gdpi=100", "-Gratio=fill", 'random_tree.dot','-o','random.png'])
randImg = Image.open("random.png")
treeSubplot.imshow(randImg, aspect = "auto")
```

With the .dot file:

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box] ;
0 [label="B field <= 332.72\nsamples = 19\nvalue = 0.41"] ;
1 [label="samples = 11\nvalue = 0.67"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="B field <= 576.73\nsamples = 8\nvalue = 0.04"] ;
0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
3 [label="samples = 4\nvalue = 0.05"] ;
2 -> 3 ;
4 [label="samples = 4\nvalue = 0.03"] ;
2 -> 4 ;
}
```

What results is the plot, but it looks extremely 'jagged', for lack of a better term:
[image: Resulting subplot]

Are there any settings I can use to stop this? I'm trying to make the image to fit the subplot perfectly but it's still jagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues.

- The image produced by `dot` is not actually the exact size you specify in `-Gsize={},{}!` parameter.
- There are rounding errors, because the matplotlib axes is positioned in relative figure coordinates and those later do not precisely match the integer positions of pixels.
- Finally, the axes to show the image in is extremely small, so the above effects become even more pronounced.

A solution one can come up with is to find the approximate size of the axes, call the `dot` program and retrieve the image from it. Then *set* the actual size of the axes according to the actual image size (this might shift the axes by a few pixels compared to their original position). 
In the code below I took a bigger axes. Also note that a higher dpi or figure size will increase the readability.

```
import numpy as np
from subprocess import check_call
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans

dpi = 100
fig = plt.figure(dpi=dpi)
gridSpec = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2)
ax = plt.subplot(gridSpec.new_subplotspec((2, 1)))
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.tick_params(axis = "both", which = "both", bottom = False, top = False, 
                        labelbottom = False, right = False, left = False, labelleft = False)
ax.set_xlabel("Final model")

# calculate nominal size supplied to `dot`
ext = ax.get_position().transformed(fig.transFigure).extents
bbox = mtrans.Bbox.from_extents(np.array(ext).astype(int))

height = bbox.height
width = bbox.width

# get image from dot
check_call(['dot','-Tpng', "-Gsize={},{}!".format(width/100, height/100),
            "-Gdpi={}".format(100), "-Gratio=fill", 'random_tree.dot','-o','random.png'])
randImg = np.array(Image.open("random.png"))

# get ACTUAL size from produced image
aheight, awidth, _ = randImg.shape

# create new bounding box from actual size
abbox = mtrans.Bbox.from_bounds(bbox.x0, bbox.y0, awidth, aheight)
# transform bbox to figure coordintes
abboxf = bbox.transformed(fig.transFigure.inverted())
# Use the thus created bbox to modify the position of the axes
ax.set_position(abboxf)

# finally plot the data
ax.imshow(randImg, aspect = "auto")
# save image (this should now be correct)
plt.savefig("randomdot_mpl.png")
# show image (this might still be slightly wrong, 
#             if the GUI changes the figure size on the fly.)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see the result is still not perfect (e.g the l in "values" is slightly thicker). In general, a much better solution might be to not place the image inside the axes at all, but to use a [`figimage`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figimage.html), which is a non-resampled image placed inside the figure. If you still want to show the axes around it, you need to make the axes transparent to "see-through".

This would be accomplished by the following code

```
import numpy as np
from subprocess import check_call
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans

dpi = 100
fig = plt.figure(dpi=dpi)
#gridSpec = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2)
#ax = plt.subplot(gridSpec.new_subplotspec((2, 1)))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.tick_params(axis = "both", which = "both", bottom = False, top = False, 
                        labelbottom = False, right = False, left = False, labelleft = False)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlabel("Final model")

# calculate nominal size supplied to `dot`
ext = ax.get_position().transformed(fig.transFigure).extents
bbox = mtrans.Bbox.from_extents(np.array(ext).astype(int))

height = bbox.height
width = bbox.width

# get image from dot
check_call(['dot','-Tpng', "-Gsize={},{}!".format(width/100, height/100),
            "-Gdpi={}".format(100), "-Gratio=fill", 'random_tree.dot','-o','random.png'])
randImg = np.array(Image.open("random.png"))

# produce a figimage, i.e. a non-resampled image
fig.figimage(randImg, xo=bbox.x0, yo=bbox.y0)

# save image (this should now be perfect)
plt.savefig("randomdot_mpl.png")
# show image (this should now be perfect)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine for a single image being the entire figure, but what if I'd like multiple images on different subplots? Would I have to take the first approach?

Comment: Both should work for several subplots as well, I just used a big subplot instead for the sake of the example.